# Create multi projects template from command line

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, project-template

I create .template.config/template.json file in solution directory and run this command dotnet new --install {Solution Path}, it create template but when i create new project from this template it only changed the name of web project not changed the other projects name.

template.json file

```
<pre>{
"$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/template",
"author": "Muhammad Ali",
"classifications": [ "NcoreReferences" ],
"identity": "NcoreReferences",
"name": "NcoreReferences",
"shortName": "NcoreReferences",
"tags": {
"language": "C#",
"type":"solution"
},
"version":"1.0.0.0",
"preferNameDirectory":true,
"symbols": {
"projectname": {
  "type": "parameter",
  "dataType": "string",
  "fileRename": "NcoreReferences",
  "replaces": "NcoreReferences"
}
},
"sources": [
{
  "modifiers": [
    {
      "exclude": ["packages/**",".vs/**"]
    }
  ]
}
] }</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

`sourceName` will be the string that is replaced during template usage with the new name. I have created complete solution with mutiple projects containing in filenames that string, as well in contents of the files.

`dotnet new` will do automatic replacement.

Here is sample repo and `sourceName`:

https://github.com/holisticware-xamarin/HolisticWare.DotNetNew.XamarinProjectsStructureTemplate/blob/master/Content/.template.config/template.json#L33

Answer (score 0):

In template.json

```
{
...
"sourceName": "OriginalTemplate",      // Will replace the string 'OriginalTemplate' with the value provided via -n.
...
}
```

Then use `-n` parameter

`dotnet new NcoreReferences -n ReplacedTemplate`

More info about dotnet templates:
[How to create your own templates for dotnet new](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/how-to-create-your-own-templates-for-dotnet-new/)